# How do I rid newline "\n" from my array of strings after populating it with fgets()?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, fgets

The array I'm working with is:

```
char arr[91][12];
```

So I populate my array from a file using a for loop like so:

```
for(i = 0; fgets(arr[i], 12, inFile); i++){}
```

When I want print anything from that array, it's automatically escaping to the next line.

to test that array:

```
for(i = 0; fgets(arr[i], 12, inFile); i++){
    printf("%s", arr[i]);
}

//one
//two
//three etc.

//want it to be 'one two three etc.'
```

I'm trying to use `strpbrk()` to find `\n` for each string in the array and change it to `\0` like this:

```
for(i = 0; fgets(arr[i], 12, inFile); i++){
if(strpbrk(arr[i], "\n") != NULL ){
    arr[i][strpbrk(arr[i], "\n")] = '\0';
    }
printf("%s", arr[i]);
}
```

but this gives me errors. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "gives me errors" is *not* an appropriate problem description for a developer.

Comment: It was for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually much simpler than you seem to think. If the newline is at the end (as it is when reading with `fgets`) just change the last character to the string terminator:

```
arr[i][strlen(arr[i]) - 1] = '\0';
```

The `-1` is because arrays (like strings can be considered to be) starts their indexing on zero and goes to `length - 1`.

---

To make sure you really *have* a newline, you can use e.g. `strpbrk` like you do (but of course not in the way you do it as explained in other answers). But I think it would be a better idea to use [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr). First because it's simpler (only searching for character not string), second because it starts searching from the end:

```
char *newlineptr = strrchr(arr[i], '\n');
if (newlineptr != NULL)
    *newlineptr = '\0';
```

---

Or the fastest way of all:

```
size_t length = strlen(arr[i]);
if (arr[i][length - 1] == '\n')
    arr[i][length - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: +1. I think `fgets` would have been better if it returned the number of characters read rather than `NULL` or the buffer you gave it.

Comment: @dreamlax: undoubtedly.  The POSIX 2008 [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) provides the length as the return value, or -1 (intriguingly, it is documented as -1, not EOF) on error or EOF.

Answer (score 4):

`strpbrk()` returns a pointer to the newline, so you should use it just once:

```
char *nl;

if ((nl = strpbrk(arr[i], "\n")) != NULL)
    *nl = '\0';
```

Alternatively, the newline will be the last character in the string, so this works too:

```
size_t len = strlen(arr[i]);
if (arr[i][len-1] == '\n')
   arr[i][--len] = '\0';
```

Note that this checks whether you got a newline; `fgets()` stops reading when it has run out of space for anything except the NUL `'\0'`, even if it has not read a newline yet.
This also gives you the length of the string (so does `strpbrk()`, indirectly; it is `nl - arr[i] - 1`).  Note that `strpbrk()` and its relative `strcspn()` are more complex than `strlen()`.

Answer (score 3):

`strpbrk` returns a *pointer* to the `'\n'`. So change:

```
arr[i][strpbrk(arr[i], "\n")] = '\0';
```

to:

```
*strpbrk(arr[i], "\n") = '\0';
```

Comment: `strpbrk` can return `NULL` though, and this will happen if the line was too large to fit into the buffer provided to `fgets()`, so best to check for `NULL` first.

Comment: @dreamlax: The OP's code *does* check for NULL, as you correctly advise.